# DDR3 10600 memory running at 533mhz

Tags: memory, hardware, hp, hp-proliant, intel

I bought a second-hand HP ProLiant DL160 G6 a year ago with 48GB configured in it. I discovered checking with cpu-z and doublechecked with speccy the memory runs at only 533Mhz. I checked the configuration with the HP memory configurator and the banks are populated correctly for max performance. There are 12 banks populated with micron and hynix memory of 4gb, all capable of running 1333mhz. What could me wrong here?

```
 C:\Users\Administrator>wmic Memorychip get manufacturer, partnumber, speed, seri
alnumber, devicelocator, banklabel
BankLabel  DeviceLocator   Manufacturer  PartNumber         SerialNumber  Speed

BANK0      PROC 1 DIMM 3A  Micron        36JSZF51272PZ1G4F  C5DF65D7      1333

BANK1      PROC 1 DIMM 2D  Micron        36JSZF51272PY1G4D  951565E0      1333

BANK3      PROC 1 DIMM 6B  Micron        36JSZF51272PZ1G4F  3F3160D6      1333

BANK4      PROC 1 DIMM 5E  Hyundai       HMT151R7BFR4C-H9   E28A3014      1333

BANK6      PROC 1 DIMM 9C  Micron        36JSZF51272PZ1G4F  26DF7E1A      1333

BANK7      PROC 1 DIMM 8F  Micron        36JSZF51272PZ1G4G  77FC67D7      1333

BANK9      PROC 2 DIMM 3A  Hyundai       HMT151R7BFR4C-H9   FB763433      1333

BANK10     PROC 2 DIMM 2D  Hyundai       HMT151R7BFR4C-H9   E18AA014      1333

BANK12     PROC 2 DIMM 6B  Hyundai       HMT151R7BFR4C-H9   DF8A1014      1333

BANK13     PROC 2 DIMM 5E  Hyundai       HMT151R7BFR4C-H9   6968511A      1333

BANK15     PROC 2 DIMM 9C  Hyundai       HMT151R7BFR4C-H9   F28A7014      1333

BANK16     PROC 2 DIMM 8F  Micron        36JSZF51272PZ1G4G  76FC67D7      1333
```

Comment: You're 100% sure that the memory is inserted the following way? http://i.imgur.com/vaSu2AC.png - also, please post the model numbers from the stickers on your RAM

Comment: Hi, see my updated answer. I'm not able to access my server at the moment (as it is in a datacentre), but will be there tomorrow.

Comment: When looking at it myself now I see the mixup with hyundai and micron across the 2 procs, could that be it?

Comment: It shouldn't matter, HP uses different memory vendors. It looks like you have inserted the memory correctly, so I have no idea what's going on here.. do you have iLO available on it?

Answer (score 8):

533MHz is not possible on this gear. This is a problem with the interpretation of the [**CPU-Z**](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) results. Multiply that frequency by the data rate (2x or DDR), giving you 1066MHz.

*But 1066MHz isn't what you were expecting either!!*

For the rest of the setup, there are a few factors to consider. The DIMM population guidelines for the server are below. You have 18 DIMM slots, and TWO DIMMs per channel are populated. That *should* give you 1333MHz, assuming all DIMMs are registered RAM (not UDIMMs). Please try a [firmware update](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/swdHome/?lang=en&cc=us&sp4ts.oid=3884344) on server and also change the BIOS setting that allows you to run *two* DIMMs/channel at 1333MHz. It should be labeled **"Two DIMMs per Channel at 1333"**.

[image]

[image]

After all of this, CPU-Z will show 666.5MHz :)

Comment: Thanks, when I'm in the serverroom I'll have a look at this setting. I put the latest BIOS on there already, not sure what firmware you're talking about.

Comment: It's a BIOS setting introduced a few years ago. Many people don't update their system firmware on HP ProLiant servers, so if the 1333MHz doesn't appear in the BIOS configuration, you have a really old firmware revision.

Comment: @Elger Did this work?

Comment: Nope, there wasn't such an option. And the bios is the latest. I'm not really experiencing performance issues with the server so I left it alone, better things to do with my time. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: @Elger You received a prompt, thorough, and well-researched response from someone who happens to be solidly within the top 1% of HP server SMEs. You can be assured that he too has better things to do with his time.

Comment: Yes, and I do appreciate that. But with his thorough answer I rebooted the server a couple of times, which interrupted a lot of users, only to find out this answer is wrong. Even if he's in the top x of famous people from hollywood, that doesn't make any difference. The latest firmware is installed and no option like this whatsoever, so after so much time investment it would be more economical to just focus on other stuff than a 10% memory performance increase I don't need.

Comment: @Elger My answer was not incorrect. It's unfortunate that your users were inconvenienced, though.

Comment: Well, again, thanks for your time, and I didn't mean to say out loud 'this is wrong!', but skyhawk kind of asked for it. But I guess this is a moot point then. An answer like "it should be labeled like ... " means you never saw it yourself on a G6. There isn't such a label and really everything is up to date. If someone else sees this answer it would be good to consider this.